# My blog load time on Bluehost and Word press is too much. I have slipped in Google Search Ranking

Tags: performance, seo, server, hosting, dns

My blog organic traffic has fallen significantly due to long load times and 50+ DNS requests from Server.

My site https://www.how2havefun.com/ loading time is more than 7 seconds.

I have Blue Host and Wordpress.

Please tell me how to solve it

I dont want to change blue host

Comment: tools.pingdom.com says it's 645ms to load, not 7 seconds... ...there doesn't appear to be a problem. Or maybe in the past 8 hours you fixed it.  If that's the case then "Good job." :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your total time for DNS is 486ms, which is OK. So the loading time issue is not with the hosting: http://prntscr.com/uw69rh

You need to optimize your site for a faster loading. It looks like getting rid of the Fontawesome alone can save you a massive 2,580ms: http://prntscr.com/uw6bd9

So start with that. Replace all of your icons with inline SVGs. Then follow the other recommendations by the PSI tool.